# Action view intent does not work

Tags: android, search-suggestion, custom-search-provider

Action view Intent for Search widget does not send Intent 
i am using Toast to show whether intent is sent when user choose item from suggestion in Quick Search Box

- here is snippet where intent is received in searchable Activity

  ```
  if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())){
     /* Intent countryIntent = new Intent(this, RecordActivity.class);
      countryIntent.setData(intent.getData());
      startActivity(countryIntent);
      */
      Toast.makeText(this,"click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      finish();
  }
  ```
- snippet from searchable.xml where search widget support Action View

> ```
> android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.Intent.action.VIEW"
> ```

there is no Uri sent at-all from `action_view` intent I do not know the reason ,although action_search work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent action names are case sensitive. Use this:

```
android.intent.action.VIEW
```